# PHP accessing webservices

Tags: php, web-services

I am trying to access this web service and it is working fine but when i come to diplay the results using the TopGoalScorersResult it is giving me this error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". Can anyone please help me with this. The $results variable is filled with the correct answers just want to display them using the method TopGoalScorersResult

```
<?php
 try {
  $client = new SoapClient(
  'http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?wsdl');
   var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
   var_dump($client->__getTypes());
   $results = $client->TopGoalScorers(array("iTopN"=>"20"));
   var_dump($results);

   echo $results->TopGoalScorersResult;

 } catch (SoapFault$e) {
     echo "<pre>" . $e->getMessage() . "</pre>";
    } 
     ?>
```

Comment: TopGoalScorersResult is atdClass. PHP tries to convert is to string to print it in SDTOUT when you call `echo $results->TopGoalScorersResult;`. Look what fields are in `TopGoalScorersResult` and echo them separately.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `TopCoalScorersResults` is an object, not a string. It presumably has properties you can access thatyou should display, rather than trying to display the object itself. You should see these in the var_dump output.

Answer (score 0):

web services in php4 you can use [SOAP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php)  on the WSDL to call the web-service functions exmaple link is here[enter link description here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.construct.php)

```
$client = new SoapClient("youridSome.wsdl");
```

and now $client is now an object . There was a method called getTime() in the WSDL then you use

```
$result = $client->getTime();
```